# fEE error using Nikon 85mm1.8 with nikon D80 camera

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, error

Does the Nikon 85mm 1.8 D work correctly with the Nikon D80 body? I just received mine today and keep getting error reading fEE when the lens is set to all apertures except f/16.

Answer (score 2):

The 'D' series lenses have an aperture ring that you can adjust on the lens.  This is different than the 'G' series which do not have that and are completely electronically controlled.

On mechanical cameras, the f/stop is set from the lens itself.  You adjust the f/stop on the lens, and then when you shoot the photo, the body closes the aperture to the appropriate setting on the lens.  This is done mechanically.

With a camera that doesn't have the capability to use the mechanical nature of the lens (the higher end professional bodies do and can use AI lenses with some restrictions), the lens needs to be set in its most stopped down position to work.  This allows the lens to be closed as far as it is capable when the aperture is controlled on the body rather than the lens.

So, yes, your lens does need to be set to its minimum aperture.  In the case of the 85mm f/1.8, this is f/16.

There is a small switch that you can flip that will *lock* the camera lens at its minimum aperture.  You will need to set it to its minimum aperture (in red-orange) and the flip the switch so that it is also pointing to the red/orange dot.

[image: 50mm nikon lens with aperture ring]

**You then control the f/stop setting from the body, not the aperture ring on the lens.**

Comment: It should also be noted that you need a camera with an internal focus motor in order to use the auto focus on this lens.
The D80 has one.
See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50517/which-nikon-dslrs-have-an-autofocus-motor-in-camera-body for a list.