# Nikin D5500 Nikon 35mm 1,8. Camera won't focus automatically

Tags: nikon, autofocus, af-s, nikon-d5500

Why do I have to manually focus in "P" ?  This lens says AF-S.   I have gone through the settings and tried using different focus settings and the camera won't auto focus but I can manally focus.  My camera is not on manual settings.
I just bought this D5500 after using my D200 since 2006. I'm a female 76 yrs old and my D200 gets too heavy when I'm hiking. I consider myself an advanced amateur. ...not a professional.
Is anyone else having this focus problem with the D 5500?

Comment: What specific AF-S lens? Are you using a teleconverter with it?

Comment: The lens itself has a focus switch (MA or M) which you  may not have engaged properly in the MA setting.  Don't currently own any Nikon kit to check this.  Perhaps also try cleaning the lens contacts.

Comment: Only in "P"? Does the lens focus automatically in Auto, S, A, M modes? If it doesn't in all of them, my first guess would be you might be using a lens that needs a screw drive from the camera body (for example the 50mm f1.8 D). Does this help https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50517/which-nikon-dslrs-have-an-autofocus-motor-in-camera-body?

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere AF-S lenses all have focusing motors built into the lens and do not require screw drives. The 50mm f/1.8 D is an AF, not AF-S, lens.

Comment: @StephenG [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871)

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871)

Comment: @MichaelClark - I was in two minds about where that belonged, but since it was more of a request for further information, I went with a comment. Looks from your point about AF-S as if it might not have been much of an answer in any case.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere The whole point is that an answer is editable and can be corrected. It's also subject to upvoting and downvoting. Comments are only editable by the commenter and only for five minutes. Then they are set in stone. They are also subject to deletion at any time.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that the shooting mode has anything to do with the autofocus settings. If you are using an AF-S lens which supports autofocus on the D5500 which I assume you are, there is a toggle switch switch on the lens itself which switches between Autofocus and manual focus settings. 
Once that is in the right place, press the information or i button and verify that the display does not say "MF" anywhere. If is does, go ahead and change that to AF and you should be good to go.
In case that still doesn't work, you might have back button focus or touch to focus enabled that might be preventing the AF.